# Abc import data from local sql server to local elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use the [ABC](https://github.com/appbaseio/abc) tool from appbase.io to import data from my local SQL server instance to my local Elasticsearch instance (running on a Docker container).

When I try using this command to do the import:

```
abc import --src_type=mssql --src_uri="sqlserver://User:P@ss@DBINSTANCE\DEV:1433?database=DBNAME" http://localhost:9200
```

I get an error that reads:

```
Panic at 48: connection error, http://localhost:9200 [recovered]
```

I can access http://localhost:9200 using `curl` without issue.

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem. In my case I had to first add an index to ElasticSearch like so:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/my-index
```

Only then I was able to use:

```
abc import --src_type=mssql --src_uri="sqlserver://User:P@ss@DBINSTANCE\DEV:1433?database=DBNAME" http://localhost:9200/my-index
```